# How to ad background image on header-panel

Tags: magento2, less-css, header.panel

so, i am trying to customise my header-panel! i want add background image insted of background color!! inside my _theme.less file

```
     .page-header {
.panel.wrapper {
     position: fixed; width: 100%; height: 100px; z-index: 5;
    .lib-css(background-color, @white);
}
```

}

this code is working fine! but i want to add image instead of that color!! what i exactly need to do?

Answer (score 0):

You can replace your code to following

```
     .page-header {
.panel.wrapper {
     position: fixed; width: 100%; height: 100px; z-index: 5;background-image:url('/pub/media/custom/background-image.png');

    .lib-css(background-color, @white);
}
```

and create a folder `custom` inside pub/media of magento installation and place your image as `background-image.png`. You can change the name of the folder and file and edit that in above code as well.